# Django middleware doesn't working template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, middleware

I implemented Django middleware for dynamic logo, site title, etc. It is working very slowly.
example. When I updated my site title, it was not updated instantly. But when I server restarted It is working.
this is my code

```
class AppBasicInfo():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.site = SiteInfo.objects.first() if SiteInfo.objects.first() else "Not Implemented"
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.site = self.site
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

settings file

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'blog.middleware.AppBasicInfo',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'blog.middleware.AppMenu',
    'blog.middleware.SocialIcon',
    'blog.middleware.DynamicYear',

]
```

and I call middleware variable as my template like `{{request.site.site_title}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` is called only once, try moving

```
self.site = SiteInfo.objects.first() if SiteInfo.objects.first() else "Not Implemented"
```

to `__call__`